# HTML/CSS - Positioning several DIV elements side by side, each div being 100% width/height of the browser

Tags: css, html, fullscreen, document-body

I can't figure this out and it's probably fairly simple. I have several DIV elements that I need placed side by side (with no margin in between), and each div must have a set width of 100% of the browser width and min-height of 100% of the browser.

Like I said I'm sure there's a quick and easy trick to this, I just couldn't find much in my research. Thank you much!

**Update: This seems to work:
http://pastebin.com/kuQyfwuG**

Comment: Do you want position absolute?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can wrap all your divs in a container div whose width is a lot bigger than the width of the browser (or at least the total width of all your divs laid side by side):

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
  width: 10000px;
  height: 100%;
}

.element {
  min-height: 100%;
  ...
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.element').css('width', window.innerWidth);
```

`body` was given the property `overflow: hidden;` so that no horizontal scrollbars will be shown because of `#container`'s size. And since giving `.element` a width of 100% will make it as wide as the `#container` element, you can add a little jQuery to make their width equal to the window's/browser's width.

Comment: wouldn't the children div (div.element) each take the width of 10000px? Since div.element has a width of 100% of #container

Comment: @AlixPërry I already edited my answer to address that issue. Thanks for pointing that out :)